# Apply font at runtime from base64 encoded string

Tags: javascript, html, fonts

I have the following situation.

The user can upload a font, later he can use it and apply it to a section of the HTML.

On my backend I'm persisting the font on an aws private bucket. when the user asks for the font to apply to an html section, I fetch the given font, base64 encode it, and send it to the front-end.

What I don't know is how to apply the bas64encoded string to an html section, and the text inside that section be rendered using the given font.

Also, I'm not a front-end developer but I need to understand if this is even possible. For images I now I can provide the encoded string to src and it works.

data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAAQAQAABAAARkZUTY8CU4cAAGbgAAAAHEdER..............very_long_string

Tried using something like this on codepen.io/

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src:  url("data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAAQAQAABAAARkZUTY8CU4cAAGbgAAAAHEdER....")
  format('ttf');
}

<body font-family="MyFont"> asdasd dasd asd as dasd asdasd asda </body>
```

Comment: **bas64encoded string to an html section**: can you please add an example of such a string?

Comment: You could theoretically reference the base64 encoded font file as a `data:` URI in an `@font-face` declaration. Might be easier if you just served the bytes (with appropriate MIME type) in response to a font file name though.

Comment: @gaetanoM, added a sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step:

change your string from:

```
data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAA.....
```

to:

```
AAEAAAA....
```

Create a dynamic style fragment into the head and use it:

```js
var strFontInbase64 = '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';

          document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<style>\
          @font-face {\
              font-family: 'myfont';\
              src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64," + strFontInbase64 + ")format('truetype');\
              font-weight: normal;\
              font-style: normal;\
          }\
          </style>");

          // use the font...

          document.querySelector('p').style['fontFamily'] = 'myfont';
```

```html
<body style="font-family: myfont">

asdasd dasd asd as dasd asdasd asda

<p> This is a demo  </p>


</body>
```